# Swift: Unicode transformations: How to generate a rainbow infinity symbol

Tags: swift, unicode

In xcode, developing for iOS "\u{1F3F3}\u{FE0F}\u{200D}\u{1F308}" is a rainbow flag.

"\u{1F3F3}" is a white flag, and "\u{1F308}" is a rainbow.  The middle symbols "\u{FE0F}\u{200D}" are invisible symbols used to join these two together to make the rainbow flag symbol.

I am trying to combine unicode characters to make a rainbow infinity symbol, but not exactly sure how to implement this.

Not sure if there is an already existing unicode character or apple api I can use to do this, but would appreciate learning how to do this

I wouldn't mind having an infinity symbol over the rainbow flag either (like the apple anti-lgbt flag incident) as an alternative.

Comment: That's not how unicode works. There's a fixed set of symbols, with images pre-baked into the fonts that devices have installed. Emojis are not procedurally generated from instructions encoded as code points.

Comment: @Alexander you would be incorrect.  A `\u{200D}` is a ZWJ character that is used to join two other unicode characters together.  For example, if you did [Man] [ZWJ] [Woman] [ZWJ] [Boy] that is how the family emoji is formed.   This is what happened with the so called `anti-lgbt` flag that people complained about.  Someone was using the ZWJ to form a crossed out rainbow flag.

Comment: interesting. I thought that the "joining" behaviour was for the sake of reducing pollution in the unicode code point table. I thought the the valid ways to join the various emoji were still hard-coded. E.g. you can't have a family of 10 people, because no graphic was made for it.

Comment: @Alexander hmmmm tbh i'm not 100% sure.  If it was hardcoded, then the anti-lgbt flag (really, anti-anything, because you can overlay that glyph onto any other emojii) probably wouldn't have existed.  That said, I know there are rules on how to combine them and rules on behaviors for every character but I don't know exactly what those are, and if a rainbow infinity, or a infinity symbol overlayed onto a rainbow flag is possible within the domain of these rules.  I'm surprised about the lack of any documentation i can find on this subject.

Comment: To be clear, many characters *are* probably procedurally created. Striked-through letters, upside down lettering, backwards lettering, etc. is all probably dynamically rendered. But Emojis rely on images baked into the font, and that only goes so far. It doesn't mean you can make a family containing a cat, a start and a hotdog.

Comment: @Alexander true, but you can make a family from any combination of person emojis.  Does that mean, every possible combination already exists?  Like policeman, firefighter, and child.

Comment: No you can't, at least I couldn't reproduce it (here's [my attempt](https://repl.it/@alexandermomchilov/Swift-Emoji-Families). You can't even switch the order of the son and daughter (daughter has to come first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emoji fonts are still just fonts. If they don’t contain a specific glyph, then they cannot display that glyph. The reason “️‍” looks like a rainbow flag is because someone drew a picture of a rainbow flag and then defined their font in such a way that the sequence `<U+1F3F3, U+FE0F, U+200D, U+1F308>` would be displayed using that specific image. Much like how someone first had to define the precise shape of the letter “A” in their font and then apply that glyph to the codepoint `U+0041`.

There is no image-rendering code that instinctively knows how to apply the colours of  to the shape of ️ and then automatically generates a new glyph on the fly. It’s all explicitly pre-defined.

`U+200D` is the so-called Zero Width Joiner (ZWJ), so emoji sequences using that character are appropriately named *Zero Width Joiner Sequences*. They were originally invented by Apple to support emoji that weren’t part of the Unicode standard (in particular, variants of , , and ️ with different gender configurations), but later other vendors jumped on board as well and nowadays they are officially part of Unicode as an alternative way for defining new emoji without having to encode entirely new characters. Currently, about a third of all officially recommended emoji are ZWJ sequences.

In theory, any person can make up their own ZWJ sequences just by joining existing characters together (as was their original intent). In your case, “♾️+ZWJ+” or `<U+267E, U+FE0F, U+200D, U+1F308>` would be an obvious sequence for a rainbow-coloured infinity symbol. You just have to create your own font containing the glyph you want, and then distribute that font to other people so that they can see the same glyph as you. There are just a few problems:

1. Making fonts with colourful glyphs is not easy. I couldn’t tell you whether there even exist freely available tools for that task.
2. There are four different formats for emoji fonts (used by Apple, Google, Microsoft, and Mozilla respectively) and they generally do not work on each other’s platforms, so you would need to create not just one, but several fonts unless you don’t care about people on other operating systems.
3. Installing your own fonts is not possible on most mobile phones, so your custom emoji would mostly only be available to desktop users.

Comment: hmm gotcha.  Is it possible to just overlay the infinity symbol onto the rainbow flag, similar to how you can overlay the `not/no` symbol over any other emoji?

Comment: That is done with the character U+20E0 COMBINING ENCLOSING CIRCLE BACKSLASH, which is a combining mark, so it automatically applies itself to the previous character: ⃠ (The actual quality of the combined glyph also depends on the font.) There is no such character for the infinity sign.